# Trying to print multiple lines in a python dictionary in order

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

```
a = "A"
b = "B"
    board = {
    "1":[a,a,a,a,a,a],
    "2":[a,a,a,a,a,a],
    "3":[a,a,a,a,a,a],
    "4":[b,b,b,b,b,b],
    "5":[b,b,b,b,b,b],
    "6":[b,b,b,b,b,b]
}
for i in board:
    print(board[str(i)],"\n")
```

I've tried doing this but it doesn't print them in order...
I've tried putting a delay on but that doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Dictionaries are not ordered in Python. You will have to populate an `OrderedDict` instead.

Comment: If you need order why not use a two-dimensional list?

Comment: Is there any particular reason why your `board` entry is a dictionary of lists, instead of a list of lists? (i.e. 2d list)

Comment: Why are you using *strings* representing numbers as the key?! If you used numbers, it would be much easier: `for i in range(1, 7)`. But a list of lists makes much more sense. *"I've tried putting a delay on but that doesn't make a difference"* - well *why on earth would it?!*

Comment: You can store dict keys, sort them and then iterate. `list = board.keys();list.sort();for i in list: pass`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean to say that the keys are not accessed in the order in which you inserted them (1, 2, 3, 4, ...)?

Dictionaries in Python are not ordered by default.
You should use an "OrderedDict"

```
from collections import OrderedDict
board = OrderedDict([("1", [a,a,a,a,a,a]), ("2", [a,a,a,a,a,a])]) # continued for other keys

for k,v in board.items():
    print k,v
```

However, like the comments say, if your keys are just numbers it would make more sense to just use a list of lists instead of a dictionary.